# R - How to rename factor levels using a function?

Tags: r, dplyr

Assume I have a function `extract_surname()` which turns "Surname, Firstname" into "Surname". How can use this function to change the levels of a factor variable?

The distinct levels of that factor are not known in advance, just that they fulfill the described naming pattern. AFAIK dplyr's `recode()` cannot be applied here, because it requires an explicit list of all substitutions to be made. Or is there a way to generate such a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the levels in the following way

```
x <- as.factor(head(letters))
x
# [1] a b c d e f
# Levels: a b c d e f

levels(x) <- toupper(levels(x))
x
# [1] A B C D E F
# Levels: A B C D E F
```

Comment: So basically `recode()` et al. are just required when single level names should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

A data.frame `df` with 2 names as factor

```
df <- data.frame('NAME' = c('Bob', 'Anna'))
levels(df$NAME)                            
[1] "Anna" "Bob"
```

I add a new name as.factor

```
levels(df$NAME)<-c(levels(df$NAME),"Terru_theTerror")
levels(df$NAME) 
[1] "Anna"            "Bob"             "Terru_theTerror"
```

You can use your function `extract_surname()` in the attribution of new levels.